# Can we use ML algorithms other than PPO in unity mlagents for multi agent like ddpg

Tags: tensorflow, unity-game-engine, ml-agent

I want to use multiple algorithms for a multi agent situation including PPO but I can't find any support for other algorithms like DDPG. If it's applicable how can I start working on it, what will be the procedure. How much changes do I have to make in other libraries in PPO.

Comment: Follow this example for clarity https://github.com/abhismatrix1/Tennis-MultiAgent